# Yii model method addError is not working

Tags: forms, yii

I have an issue about displaying error in a yii form.

#### This is my controller:

```
$custom_user->attributes = $_POST['CustomUser'];
if($custom_user->validate())
{
  ...
  save
  ...
}
else
{
  $custom_user->addError('username', 'Error X');
  $this->redirect(array('access/index'),
                  array('user'=>$custom_user,
                        'tab'=>$tab_person,
  ));
}
```

#### This is my index view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('BaseForm', array(
                            'id'=>'user-form',
                           'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('person/createUser'))); ?>

 <?php echo $form->errorSummary($user);?>

 <div class="right">
        <?php echo $form->textField($user,'username',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <br/><?php echo $form->error($user,'username'); ?>
    </div>
  ...
  ...
 <div style="float: left;">
        <?php echo $form->dateField($user,'valid_from',null,'valid_from_formated'); ?>
        <br/><?php echo $form->error($user,'valid_from'); ?>
 </div>
```

#### Here is my BaseForm

```
public $enableClientValidation = true;
public $enableAjaxValidation = true;
public $clientOptions = array(  'hideErrorMessage'=>false,
                                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                                'validateOnChange'=>false,
                                'validateOnType'=>false,
                                'afterValidateAttribute' => 'js:enableSubmitAV',
                                'afterValidate' => 'js:submitFormAV'); // always fires this after
```

#### Here is the problem:

"$form->errorSummary($user);" is empty
and noting is display under "$form->error($user,'username');"

But if I look in Firebug I can see that under "response" tab:

> {"CustomUser_valid_until":["Valid Until must be
>   greater than \"20121127\"."]}

it's a good thing because it means my rules work great. But none errors are displayed. Not this one and even the error "Error X" I add in my controller is not diplayed... (I'm sure I pass throught the else statement, i tried it).

So, does anyone could have an idea?

Thanks for reading me and sorry for my approximate English.

Have a good day :)

Michaël

Comment: check in firebug if html generated with display none ?

Comment: It's really strange. Because under the tab HTML of my response all is correct (errors are displayed) but in my page nothing and when I look at the source code there are no errors even hidden. It looks like if the browser doesn't diplay what the serveur give him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting, meaning a whole new request is called, and any responses are deleted.

Why are you redirecting to "access/index" rather than just calling the view?  If you do need to redirect, which you definitely can, try setting a flash variable as it is store in the browser's session and will persist through redirects:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('username', "Error X");
```

Then on the access/index page:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('username')):?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('username'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, just use $this->render('access/index', array('user'=>$custom_user, 'tab'=>$tab_person,));

Comment: Hello, Thank you you're both right. Actually I don't know why I used a redirect...I changed that with render('index', array('user'=>$custom_user, 'tab'=>$tab_person,)); but errors still don't appear. But if I look in firebug in the "html" tab I can see the errors written on my page. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I got what was wrong. It was the configuration in my CActiveForm. The option "enableAjaxValidation" seems to make some problem when it's on "true". I don't know really why but I've already had this problem with a login form befor. I'll try to work out this problem.